# Python plotly: How do I set up x.xx% format on Yaxis

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, plotly

My project is to scrape data from https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield and create a plotly line chart.

My problem is while I've scraped data I can create same table, but when I'm trying to apply this data to plotly chart I can't get yaxis. My goal is to show on Yaxis data in format x.xx%

I don't know if this is the wrong data I'm scraping or the code I'm using.

My current code is:

```
treasury_url = 'https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldAll'
    
    
    df = requests.get(treasury_url)
    html = df.text
    
    soup= BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    
    table = soup.find('table', {"class": "t-chart"})
    
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    data = []
    for row in rows[1:]:
        cols = row.find_all('td') # find all rows in a table
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', '1 mo', '2 mo','3 mo', '6 mo', '1 yr', '2 yr', '3 yr', '5yr', '7 yr', '10 yr', '20 yr', '30 yr'])

fig=go.Figure()

fig = px.line(df, x='Date', title='Daily Treasury Yield Curve Rates')

fig.update_xaxes(
    rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(count=1, label="5d", step="day", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=1, label="1m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=3, label="3m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=6, label="6m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=1, label="YTD", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
            dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=5, label="5y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=10, label="10y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(step="all", label='All')
        ])
    )
)

fig.update_layout(title='20 Year Treasury Rate',
                    width=1200,
                    height=600,
                
                 xaxis = dict(
                     type='date',
                     linewidth=1,
                     showgrid=False,
                     title='',
                     tickangle=-45,
                     tickformat='%Y',
                     tickfont=dict(
                         size=12
                         )
                     ),
                 yaxis = dict(
                     linewidth=0.5,
                     title='Interest rate',
                     tickformat=".2%",
                     tickfont=dict(
                         size=12
                         )
                     )
                 )

fig.show()
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi AnnaAi, welcome on SO. Please have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask). In particular you should open a different question for every point.

Comment: Thank you @rpanai, I've edited the question, how this will be more clear now.

Comment: Hi @AnnaAI please let me know if my answer was useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't take this as an answer (at least not yet) as you are asking several questions at once and this is against SO rules.

## Get data

Here `pandas` is your friend and you could avoid `BeautifulSoup` using `pd.read_html`as following

```py
import pandas as pd
treasury_url = 'https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldAll'

# this returns all the tables from a webpage 
dfs = pd.read_html(treasury_url)

# the second one is the one you need
df = dfs[1]

# convert date to datetime
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('M8')
```

## Plot one line only

```py
import plotly.express as px

# as you want data as percentage 
# you might consider to scale it first
df[df.columns[1:]] = df[df.columns[1:]]/100
 
fig = px.line(df, x='Date',y='1 mo', title='Daily Treasury Yield Curve Rates')
fig.update_layout(title_x=0.5, yaxis=dict(tickformat=".2%"))
```

[image]

From here you should plot all possible line (eventually with `plotly.graph_objects`) and play with the visible argument.

Comment: Thank you @rpanai the graph works as it's shown above.